# I have a dart board. How can I assign points for the different sections?

Tags: math, geometry

**PLEASE do not just post a solution to my problem. For me, this is all about understanding how to do this and be able to explain to myself and others how this and that makes it all work!**

I have a dart board I created with turtle. I can post it if someone really wants to see it.

Now, I need to create a function that will create a random spot on the board to hit, then incorporate the point value for that spot. The random point is simple. But is there a way that I can assign the correct value to an AREA without having to name EVERY coordinate one by one?

Comment: you could pick a random number between [0, 360) and a number between [0, radius) then use these as an angle and offset from origin.

Answer (score 1):

Say your dart board is centered at `(x0, y0)`, and you have a dart at `(x, y)`. You need to translate your dart into [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) `(phi, r)`:

```
r = sqrt((x - x0) ** 2, (y - y0) ** 2)
phi = math.atan2(y, x)
```

Then figure out whether `r` makes your dart is in center, inner, mid or outer ring, and in which section of the circle your `phi` lies.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a reverse transform, one that given x,y coordinates can identify which area it belongs to.

The best way to deal with this problem is to think in terms of coordinate systems. The area of a dart board is specified by its angle and radius. You must convert your x,y coordinates to an angle and radius, then determining the area it falls within will be simple.

Determining the angle is best done with an `arctan2` function, which can directly convert an x,y offset into an angle. The radius is a simple `sqrt(x**2 + y**2)` once you have subtracted the center point from x,y.

Answer (score 0):

good ol' [Pythagoras](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm)

[image]

Let the point (x1, y1) be the center of the dart board that is used from the constructor. and let (x2, y2) be the random point on the board you find.

Use this formula to find d the distance from the center. Then you just need a few if statements

```
if 0 <= d || d <= 2:
    # area 0
elif d < 2 || 4 <= d:
    # area 1
elif d < 4 || 6 <= d:
    # area 2
```